# Forward Engineering EER Diagram returns ERROR 1103

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-schema

I'm currently working on a project that required me to create a DB Model in MySQL Workbench. After I finished editing the EER Diagram, I tried to forward engineer my diagram to a Database. However, the SQL code generated fails to execute and returns the following message:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1103: Incorrect table name ''
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `mydb`.``
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`` (
        )
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

I'm in the dark here. Any help would be appreciated.

If needed, I can upload a .png image with the diagram.

Comment: All I can think of is that you have an "empty" table definition somewhere that's being applied first.

Comment: I'll look for it. Will be updating here soon if I find something.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I inspected the object navigator and there was an empty table that was not referenced inside the diagram. I managed to delete it and the script ran as intended.

Comment: Could you please add your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can think of is that you have an "empty" table definition somewhere that's being applied first.

Thanks!